# How to grouping with distinct or group max sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, max, grouping, distinct

i have date like this Data

```
id      name period difference 
6172    A      6      10 
6172    A      3      10 
10099   AB     12     24 
10099   AB     6      24 
10099   AB     3      24 
10052   ABC    12     26 
10052   ABC    6      26 
10052   ABC    3      26 
9014    ABCD   12     21 
9014    ABCD   6      21 
9014    ABCD   3      21
```

how to get result like this

```
id      name    period  difference
6172    A         6      10
10099   AB        12     24
10052   ABC       12     26
9014    ABCD      12     4
```

i try with distinct on (id), but the result like this

```
id     name    period   difference
6172    A         6      10
10099   AB        6      24
10052   ABC       6      26
9014    ABCD      6      4
```

Comment: why for 9014 period=3 and difference=4?

Comment: Why should ABCD result in 3, The max value is 12 as well..

Comment: The expected difference for `ABCD` is still off, and should be 21, not 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query you want looks something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) *
FROM Data
ORDER BY id, period DESC;
```

[image]

### Demo

This is probably the most efficient way to write your query on Postgres.  Note that `DISTINCT ON` syntax does not support more than one column in the `ON` clause.  The above logic happens to work here assuming that `id` would uniquely identify each group (that is, that `id` would always be unique).  If not, then we might have to resort to using `ROW_NUMBER` with a partition over `id` and `name.`

Comment: The comma before `*` should probably not be there, but otherwise probably what the asker is looking for.

Comment: @YonathanRizkyNathanael Shana tovah bro :-P

Answer (score 0):

using `max()`

```
select id, name, t2.period, difference from tableA t1
inner join 
 (select id, max(period) as period from tableA
 group by id) t2 on t2.id = t1.id
```

using `distinct()`

```
select distinct id, name, t2.period, difference from tableA
```

Comment: thank you sir, for helping, I can't use max (period), because the period field is an alias field from the previous query

Answer (score 0):

it seems you need just `max()`

```
select id,name,max(period),max(difference)
from table group by id,name
```

Though i have not found difference=4 in your sample data but you used that on output,so i guessed its your typo

Comment: thank you sir, for helping, I can't use max (period), because the period field is an alias field from the previous query

Answer (score 0):

Use `max()`

```
select id, name, max(period), difference from tablename
group by id, name,difference
```

Comment: thank you sir, for helping, I can't use max (period), because the period field is an alias field from the previous query

Answer (score 0):

You can try my code:

```
SELECT
  id, name, max(period), difference
FROM 
  data_table
group by id, name,difference
order by name
```

This is a demo link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9ab8d/2

Comment: thank you sir, for helping, I can't use max (period), because the period field is an alias field from the previous query